# How to find the index of the top cell of the table view Even when it is scrolling in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a table view. Now I need to know the index of the top of the table view cell. 
For example when we scroll down the topmost table view cell changes. I always want the top of the table view cell is returned.

Comment: The first indexPath of [indexPathsForVisibleRows](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614885-indexpathsforvisiblerows?changes=_6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let visiableCells = tableView.visibleCells
    if let cell = visiableCells.first as? InfoTableViewCell {
        print(cell.textLabel?.text)
    }
}
```

Where `InfoTableViewCell` is Custom Cell

Answer (score 0):

Use this property of `UITableView`

```
var visibleCells: [UITableViewCell] { get }
```

to get the first visible cell

```
let firstVisibleCell = yourTableView.first
```

Read more from [Appledoc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614896-visiblecells?changes=_6)

Comment: Given how quickly that changes, it would probably work best as a getter.

Comment: it depends, how frequently the OP wants to get the first item.

Comment: @RatulSharker I want it to happen all the time. A label at the top has to change according to the topmost cell index.